# Pandas - apply truth value is ambiguous when parameter is entered

Tags: python, pandas

**Why does this work?**

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


master = pd.read_csv(
    "C:/Users/grego/Downloads/Specific Drug monitoring.csv"
    , skiprows=11, na_values=["no info", "."])

 pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
    if s['Apixaban'] != '' and s["CRCL"] > 60:
        x = 12
    elif s['Apixaban'] != '' and 60 > s["CRCL"] > 30:
        x = 6
    elif s['Apixaban'] != '' and s["CRCL"] < 30:
        x = 3
    if x != 45:
        return s['RFT'] + timedelta(days=30*x)
    else:
        return ''


master['RFT required'] = master.apply(RFT,axis=1)
master.to_csv("Category3 testing v01.csv",index=False)
```

**But this doesn't**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Reads base population into python - skipping headers - make sure patients details are duplicated on every line on export
master = pd.read_csv(
    "C:/Users/grego/Downloads/Specific Drug monitoring.csv"
    , skiprows=11, na_values=["no info", "."])

# ref = pd.read_csv("Category3 ref.csv",index_col=0,na_values=["no info"])

master = master.rename(
    columns={'Name, Dosage and Quantity': 'Ace', 'Name, Dosage and Quantity.1': 'Amiodarone',
             'Name, Dosage and Quantity.2': 'Apixaban', 'Value': 'CRCL', 'Code Term': 'ADHD', 'Date': 'Heart Rate',
             'Date.6': "RFT"})
master2 =master

def RFT(s,y):
    x = 45
    s[['RFT']] = s[['RFT']].apply(
        pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
    if s['Apixaban'] != '' and s[y] > 60:
        x = 12
    elif s['Apixaban'] != '' and 60 > s[y] > 30:
        x = 6
    elif s['Apixaban'] != '' and s[y] < 30:
        x = 3
    if x != 45:
        return s['RFT'] + timedelta(days=30*x)
    else:
        return ''


master['RFT required'] = master.apply(RFT(master,"CRCL"),axis=1)
master.to_csv("Category3 testing v01.csv",index=False)
```

returning the error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I am very new to python and pandas so go easy on me haha. Just confused about how entering a parameter has caused the series to become ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe try to replace 'and' by '&'